# Tracking Changes in document by different editors

Tags: 2013, document-library, versioning, co-authoring

We use co authoring in our SP 2013 portal. Different users with edit permission work on the same document and on saving a minor version is created. Can the document owner (creator) track this changes once all of them have saved (who has edited what)

Answer (score 0):

Enable versioning for document library.
Following are the steps

1.Go to Library setting.

2.Click On versioning setting

3.Select appropriate option for versioning.

options:-

1.Create major versions
Example: 1, 2, 3, 4
2.Create major and minor (draft) versions
Example: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0)